# Difference between functioning of net.Listen and http.ListenAndServe

Tags: go, server, network-programming, go-http

I'm new to Go and Networking. I know both net.Listen and http.ListenAndServe creates a server. But what is the difference between their functionality?

Comment: The one (from package net) is a low level tcp/udp connection while the other (from net/http) implements a HTTP server. The first is a basic network connection, while the other is a full fledged implementation of HTTP _on_ _top_ of low level conncection(s).

Comment: Thanks for this! But what did you mean by _low level connections_?

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model) according to which TCP is level 4 and HTTP is layer 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, as the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen) says for `net.Listen`: `The network must be "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6", "unix" or "unixpacket".`

While `http.ListenAndServe` creates an HTTP server.